# Elegant way to find min/max in a table (vector of vectors, 2D array) using STL algorithm(s)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Let us assume we have a vector of vectors and wish to find a minimum (or maximum) values (no need to know their position in the table). What would be an elegant way to accomplish this?

The obvious solution, included below, is to run std::min_element per each row in a loop. But may be it is possible to do it with a single statement without loop using, may be, lambda functions?

Note, there is a similar question on SO already, but it is actually not quite about what I am asking here.

Update: Ideal solution would be using STL only, but, failing that, it would be interesting to see other options.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > test_array=
         {
          {1., 2., 3., 4.},
          {7., 4., 6., 8.},
          {5., -1., 3., 1}
         };
    double min_val(test_array[0][0]);
    double max_val(test_array[0][0]);
    for(auto& row : test_array)
    {
        min_val = std::min(min_val, *std::min_element(row.begin(), row.end()));
        max_val = std::max(max_val, *std::max_element(row.begin(), row.end()));
    }

    cout << "Minimum = " << min_val << std::endl;
    cout << "Maximum = " << max_val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the algorithms return an iterator, so you can't do `std::max_element(begin(array), end(array), 0, [](){})` because you would need to return an iterator on a vector, and not on an element :/

Comment: With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), there is `ranges::view::join` to see the range of ranges as flattened range, then a simple `std::minmax_element` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Jarod42 Any chance for an answer based on it?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: unsure it is fine for OP to use external lib.

Comment: I would vote for @Jarod42. Find a way to view the vector of vector by one iterator. This could be done some iterator that knows about all vectors. Or you drop the vector of vector for a simple vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options, e.g., the following one uses `std::accumulate` that returns pair of numbers containing minimum and maximum elements, respectively:

```
auto res = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), std::make_pair(a[0][0], a[0][0]),
    [](const auto& current, const auto& v) {
        auto minmax = std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
        return std::make_pair(std::min(current.first, *minmax.first),
                              std::max(current.second, *minmax.second));
    });
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/IwMWioewJBg7C67l

Comment: Interesting solution. I accept is as an answer as it is formally correct. Basically it answers my question -- it is possible, but the result is neither elegant nor easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @one_two_three Agree, we cannot have both. Hopefully, ranges will get into C++20.

Answer (score 2):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might have a flatten view with `ranges::view::join`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > test_array =
{
    {1., 2., 3., 4.},
    {7., 4., 6., 8.},
    {5., -1., 3., 1}
};
auto flatten_view = test_array | ranges::view::join;
const auto p = std::minmax_element(begin(flatten_view), end(flatten_view));
std::cout << "Minimum = " << *p.first << std::endl;
std::cout << "Maximum = " << *p.second << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a58e94c1aaee52)

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your solution as it is definitely elegant and easy to understand, although it is outside the STL at the moment. Well, I guess one cannot have both.